# Changing the class of an element by the link we navigate from

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress, where I'm able to modify the html, php and css. I have a scenario as follows:

PageA has two links: Link1 and Link2.

PageB has two tabs: Tab1 and Tab2.

Link1 and Link2 should both navigate to PageB, BUT I want to make it such that when user clicks on Link1, he navigates to PageB as Tab1 open; and when he clicks on Link2, he navigates to PageB as Tab2 open.

Currently, the open tab has two css classes which the closed one doesn't have. When the closed tab is selected, it acquires those two classes and the open one loses those classes.

Now, my question is; is there a way to make Tab2 have those classes instead of Tab1 if I click to Link2? I should better do it with the resources I have; html, php, css. So, better no JavaScript.

Edit: I implement the tabs by Wordpress plugins but they are created like the following in html (Tab1 is open here and Tab2 is closed):

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-1-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-8" aria-selected="true">
        <a href="#tabs-1-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-8">MyTab1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-1-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-9" aria-selected="false">
        <a href="#tabs-1-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-9">MyTab2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My links are simply:

```
<a title="Link1" href="http://mywebpage.com/?page_id=60">
<a title="Link2" href="http://mywebpage.com/?page_id=60">
```

Comment: Exactly how your tabs code look like?? post some code or if you can make a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

you need to create active class on click bind that class to the tab you clicked on!!